# snowflake: using query id, how to get the details of the

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using python connector and ingesting some big data into a table.

Now i want to get the query history details like

[image]

How can i get the bytes scanned and total duration form the history knowing the query id of the query.

the below is the python code

```
import snowflake
import snowflake.connector

con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    account=eeeeeeeeee,
    user=xxxxxxxxxxxx,
    password=yyyyyyyyyyy,
    warehouse=zzzzzzzzzzzzz,
    database=dddddddddddddd,
)

try:
  cmd=f"""
      copy into "DB1"."SCH1"."TB1"
      from s3://bucket1/folder1/ credentials=(aws_key_id='xxxxxxxxxx' aws_secret_key='yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
      file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1)
      on_error = 'continue';
      """
  res = con.execute_string(cmd)
  query_id = x._sfqid[0]  
  # I am getting the query id here. 
  # Using this how to get the details. 
  # (bytes scanned, total time take as shown in history)
  con.commit()
  return res
except Exception as e:
    raise e
finally:
    con.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this to get this information from the account_usage schema:

```sql
select bytes_scanned, total_elapsed_time, query_id from snowflake.account_usage.query_history
where query_id = 'YOUR_QUERY_ID'
```

Comment: bytes scanned is showing zero. i can see bytes scaneed on the history page.